# Report Server Windows Service (MSSQLSERVER) cannot connect to the report server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-mirroring

I have 2 SQL Servers, 1 principal and 1 mirror on a remote site. On the mirrored server, the following error is being logged.

> Report Server Windows Service (MSSQLSERVER) cannot connect to the report server database.
>
> The application domain WindowsService_17 failed to initialize. Error: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerDatabaseUnavailableException: The report server cannot open a connection to the report server database. A connection to the database is required for all requests and processing.
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "ReportServer" requested by the login. The login failed.
>
> Login failed for user 'MYDOMAIN\sqladmin'.
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)

```
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnection owningObject)

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(String host, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Int64 timerStart)

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)

at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)

at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)

at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)

at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)

at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)

at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()

at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ConnectionManager.OpenConnection()

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ConnectionManager.OpenConnection()

at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ConnectionManager.ConnectStorage()

at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ServiceController.ServiceStartThread(Object firstStart).
```

TCP/IP and Named Pipes are enabled on both servers. When I open up the Report Server Configuration Manager on both servers, the settings match.

`OURDOMAIN\sqladmin` set up as the service account. SQL Server Reporting Services are running under the `OURDOMAIN\sqladmin` service account.

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: Error seems pretty clear: your sqladmin account can't login to the database. Have you verified that account's permissions on the db?